# html5 basic alert and textbox

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I am a newbie in HTML5 and javascript. 
I want an alert box to display data(firstname and lastname). 
Data must be taken from textboxes on the form.
My code is below, but the alertbox doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>

</form>
<script>
function display_alert()
  {
   alert(fname +lname);
  }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="display_alert()" value="Display alert box">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give ids to inputs tags

```
   <form>
        <input id="a" type="text"/>
        <input id="b" type="text"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="display_alert();" />
    </form>
```

and then use them inside your js code:

```
<script lang="javascript">
    function display_alert() {
        var fn = document.getElementById('a');
        var ln = document.getElementById('b');
        alert(fn.value + ' ' + ln.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and maybe it is time to get and use jquery :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery.

html:

```
First name: <input type="text" id='fname' /><br>
Last name: <input type="text"  id='lname'/><br>
<input type="button" onclick="display_alert();" value="Display alert box">
```

script:

```
function display_alert() {
    fname = $('#fname').val();
    lname = $('#lname').val();
    alert(fname+' '+lname);
}​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XGrpf/#update)

Jquery might be useful for the future.

Comment: Don't suggest jQuery on a simple JS question, especially if the question's not tagged with jq.

Comment: @Cerbrus, jquery should use in future. that's why i'm suggested 'jquery'.

Comment: @KarSho: What do you mean, _"Should use"_? And why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get values using [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) function in your script.

Try changing your script with below one.

```
<script> 
  function display_alert()
  {
     var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
     var lname = document.getElementsByName("lname")[0].value;
     alert(fname + ' ' + lname); 
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** Just for your information, there is no relation with `HTML5` to this.

Comment: That'll log: `[Object HTMLTextAreaElement] [Object HTMLTextAreaElement]`. You forgot the `.value`.
Also, I'd suggest adding a `getElementById` example.

Comment: thank you. Sorry for this. I want to create a HTML widget in fact. Now I am trying to learn html logic. I can't seperate html and html5 directly.